# making wireless work in ubuntu12.10

Tags: 12.10, wireless, ralink

I installed ubuntu12.10 on a win8 lappy. But the wireless does not seem to work. 
Here are some of the details that you might be interested in. So as of now my machine is in a state where I can't connect to the internet, however I have another machine that connects to internet.

Please let me know, what is wrong with my laptops wireless settings and how do I install drivers if any.

Below is some data that you might be interested in.

```
sudo lshw -c network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.2
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.2
       logical name: eth0
       version: 0a
       serial: 6c:3b:e5:7c:86:f6
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-1_0.0.3 06/18/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:44 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c0404000-c0404fff memory:c0400000-c0403fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Ralink corp.
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c0510000-c051ffff


lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5289 (rev 01)
01:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 0a)
02:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. Device 3290
02:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. Device 3298

 rfkill list all
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Answer (score 0):

RaLink are pretty well known for working out of the box. I assume this is your built in wireless card. What kind of laptop is it? Need to find out what the wireless adapters is to find out about drivers.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from lspci log you have RT3290 chipset. I have checked Ubuntu driver located at drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00 and it doesn't support this chip. Could you please post here output of the following command?

dmesg | grep rt2

I recently has solved my problem with RT5392 chipset, but it was easier 'cos 5390 is supported and 5392 is close to 5390. You chipset may be supported on resent 3.7/3.8 kernel. Check out following thread, looks like the guy solved the problem

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2104129